# Рассчитать скорость метода в Java - сравнить, что быстрее

Tags: java, простые-числа

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я рассчитываю скорость выполнения методов `eratosthenes(int n)` и `countPrimes(int max)`? Точнее, что не так с ними?
Почему в первом варианте у меня выдает постоянно новые значения времени?
А во втором варианте с другим методом вообще возвращает 0...

```
/**
 * Defines whether the integer is prime or not
 */
public boolean isPrime(int p){
    int div = 2;
    while (div<p){
    if (p%div == 0){
    return false;
    }
    div ++;
    }
    return true;
}


 /**
 * Print out the set of prime numbers within defined maximum.
 * @param max All the numbers should be chosen within the
 * max border
 */
public int countPrimes(int max){
  ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
  int amount= 0;
  for (int i=1; i<=max; i++){
    if (isPrime(i) == true){ 
        numbers.add(i);

    }
  }
  amount = numbers.size();
  return amount;
}
/**
 * Return false if the index of an array is not a prime number.
 */
public boolean[] eratosthenes (int n){
 boolean []P = new boolean [n];
 Arrays.fill(P,2,n,true);
 for (int i=1; i<n; i++){
    if (P[i]){
         for(int j = 2*i; j < n; j +=i){
            P[j] = false;
        }
    }
 }
 return P;
}

   /**
 * Count the time of method eratosthenes.
 */
private long countTimeEratosthenes(int n){
long start = System.nanoTime();
eratosthenes(n);
long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
 // System.out.println("The time spend by eratosthenes() method is: " + elapsedTime );
return elapsedTime;

}

    /**
 * Count the time of method countPrimes().
 */
private long countTimePrimes(int n){

long start = System.nanoTime();
countPrimes(n);
long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
//System.out.println("The time spend by countPrimes() method is: " + elapsedTime );
return elapsedTime; 

}

/**
 * Prints out the time spend on calculations by methods eratosthenes (int n) 
 * and countPrimes(int max).
 * @param n The prime numbers must be chosen till this maximum point.
 */
public void compareMethods(int n){
    System.out.println("The elapsed time of a method countTimeEratosthenes(int n) is: " +
    countTimeEratosthenes(n) + "\n"+
    "The elapsed time of a method countPrimes() is: " + countTimePrimes(n));
}
```

}

Comment: Помимо выполнения кода вашей программы в JVM происходит ещё множество закулисных процессов, влияющих на общее время выполнения, поэтому вопрос точных измерений - это вопрос сложный. Посмотрите в сторону [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Comment: Первый раз вы берете наносекунды, а второй раз - миллисекунды.

Comment: Во время компиляции компилятор оптимизирует все возможные места и всвязи с этим некоторые процессы могут произойти быстрее, чем мы ожилали)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev нам просто дали задание, определить, какой метод лучше eratosthenes() или countPrimes(). И теперь я не могу определить, какой же метод быстрее...

Comment: @StasDorozhko но второй метод с милисекундами почему-то не работает

Comment: @МайяБареева добавьте пожалуйста main или test который вызывает countTime и countTime1, а то не понятно который из них первый, а который второй вариант, а также на каких n вы производите замеры.

Comment: @Ramiz вроде бы исправила, создала метод, который сравнивает два метода eratosthenes() и countPrimes(). Обычно как n всегда фиксированное число ввожу, 20, и по этому примеру смотрю результаты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как верно заметили в комментариях к вопросу, для точных измерений производительности надо использовать специализированные средства.
если же строгих требований к точности нет, то можно воспользоваться "дедовским методом", который вы собственно уже и начали применять, осталось лишь немного доработать - скомпенсировать неточность измерения многократным выполнением теста и сравнением среднего значения.

```
public void compareMethods2(int start, int end, int step) throws InterruptedException
{
    // warmup: let JIT do its work
    for(int n = start; n < end; n += step)
    {
        countTimeEratosthenes(n);
        countTimePrimes(n);
    }
    // yield: let JIT finish its work
    Thread.sleep(1000L);

    final int runsPerN = 100;
    int testsCount = (end - start) / step;
    long[][][] times = new long[testsCount][2][runsPerN];
    // compare:
    int n = start;
    for(int i = 0; i < testsCount; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < runsPerN; j++)
        {
            times[i][0][j] = countTimeEratosthenes(n);
            times[i][1][j] = countTimePrimes(n);
        }

        n += step;
    }

    // report:
    System.out.println("| N\t| M1 (min / avg / max)\t\t| M2 (min / avg / max)\t\t |");
    for(int i = 0; i < times.length; i++)
    {
        long min1 = Arrays.stream(times[i][0]).min().getAsLong();
        long max1 = Arrays.stream(times[i][0]).max().getAsLong();
        double avg1 = Arrays.stream(times[i][0]).average().getAsDouble();

        long min2 = Arrays.stream(times[i][1]).min().getAsLong();
        long max2 = Arrays.stream(times[i][1]).max().getAsLong();
        double avg2 = Arrays.stream(times[i][1]).average().getAsDouble();

        int Ni = start + i * step;

        System.out.printf("| %4d | %8d %10.2f %8d | %8d %10.2f %8d |%n", Ni, min1, avg1, max1, min2, avg2, max2);
    }
}

@Test
public void testComparePrimesTimes() throws Exception
{
    compareMethods2(20, 2000, 100);
}
```

получаем примерно следующее:

```
| N | M1 (min / avg / max)      | M2 (min / avg / max)       |
|   20 |     2025    2640.27    25271 |     2733    3145.01    17636 |
|  120 |     2023   10179.19    41346 |    18341   24489.80    69333 |
|  220 |     2950    4608.45    43856 |    21166   32399.33    93247 |
|  320 |     3808    6912.41    49975 |    34500   43912.05    76763 |
|  420 |      921    2768.91    30108 |    50044   53670.56   105743 |
|  520 |     1129    1886.35    18319 |    63060   76660.16   114759 |
|  620 |     1313    1805.31     4100 |    91406   96015.85   136968 |
|  720 |     1593    2112.06     4612 |   116769  124864.66   184700 |
|  820 |     1787    2460.56     5130 |   145137  151346.46   211378 |
|  920 |     2019    2913.17    15376 |   181420  190582.67   253804 |
| 1020 |     2236    3049.34     7007 |   217765  229690.78   304122 |
| 1120 |     2579    3897.28    13347 |   264511  296067.06   488041 |
| 1220 |     2704    4356.16    25338 |   303249  320122.91   415772 |
| 1320 |     3094    4794.53    19408 |   356526  377768.69   498047 |
| 1420 |     3254    4876.34    13953 |   384434  407723.93   535515 |
| 1520 |     3519    5171.80    14009 |   451568  477981.40   566432 |
| 1620 |     3899    5634.93    10263 |   517559  558915.03   748623 |
| 1720 |     4298    6143.41    22676 |   565783  594867.70   766325 |
| 1820 |     4638    6573.38    17182 |   629233  662417.47   880321 |
```

из чего видно, что eratosthenes работает достаточно стабильно, когда countPrimes растет практически линейно с ростом n. Очевидно это связано с особенностями реализации последнего, т.е. с тем что он пересчитывает каждое  простое число заново не используя уже рассчитанные. Но даже оптимизировав этот метод так чтобы проверять делимость не на все числа подряд, а на уже известные простые числа (кстати, ваш метод содержал ошибку - учитывал 1 как простое число)

```
// see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primzahl
public int countPrimes(int max)
{
    if(max < 2)
        return 0;

    int[] primes = new int[max];
    primes[0] = 2;
    int count = 1;

    for(int x = 3; x <= max; x += 2)
    {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int p = primes[i];
            if(x % p == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime)
        {
            primes[count++] = x;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

все равно не удается "догнать" первый метод. Это связано с тем что операция % (остаток от деления) [достаточно затратная операция](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785615/is-modulo-slow-in-java) в то время как второй метод использует только умножение на 2 и сложение приблизительно при том же количестве итераций.